# WiFi cannot get IP from WPA2 Personal authenticated AP on 6.5.0-14 kernel, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless

Recently, my laptop failed to connect to my personal access point (AP). However, it was able to connect to the public AP. Personal AP uses WPA2 Personal authentication, and public AP uses WPA2 Enterprise (802.1x?) authentication.

After looking at `/var/log/syslog`, `dmsg` and the log of the personal AP, I found that my laptop failed to receive the IP from the AP after the AP's DHCP assigned an IP.

Until recently, the WiFi connection to the personal AP was working well, so I wanted to check if there was a problem with the recent update or kernel, so I booted the previous version, 6.2.0-39-generic kernel, and it connected to the personal AP correctly.
(The recent kernel package version is 6.5.0-14-generic.)

There seems to be a problem with the recent kernel or device driver update. Where and how should I report this?

`lspci | grep Network`:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 0608
```

connection part of `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5641] device (wlp1s0): Activation: starting connection 'pap_2g' (f96ae302-8ebf-4cb3-9a37-cd88b303b9a5)
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5649] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5649] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5658] device (wlp1s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5661] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5664] device (wlp1s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5671] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'pap_2g' has security, but secrets are required.
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5671] device (wlp1s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5685] device (wlp1s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5688] device (wlp1s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5694] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'pap_2g' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5694] Config: added 'ssid' value 'pap_2g'
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5694] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5695] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5695] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5695] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381358.5695] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Jan 16 14:02:38 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: Failed to initiate AP scan
Jan 16 14:02:39 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381359.6130] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 16 14:02:39 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381359.6132] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 16 14:02:39 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Jan 16 14:02:40 xxxxxx-laptop2 google-chrome.desktop[2897]: [2891:2920:0116/140240.513351:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
Jan 16 14:02:40 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Jan 16 14:02:40 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: message repeated 2 times: [ wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN]
Jan 16 14:02:40 xxxxxx-laptop2 dbus-daemon[643]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.157' (uid=1000 pid=10052 comm="gnome-control-center " label="unconfined")
Jan 16 14:02:40 xxxxxx-laptop2 systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jan 16 14:02:41 xxxxxx-laptop2 dbus-daemon[643]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jan 16 14:02:41 xxxxxx-laptop2 systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jan 16 14:02:42 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Jan 16 14:02:42 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: message repeated 2 times: [ wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN]
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 70:5d:cc:xx:xx:xx (SSID='pap_2g' freq=2432 MHz)
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 kernel: [ 1020.707351] wlp1s0: authenticate with 70:5d:cc:xx:xx:xx
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 kernel: [ 1020.726674] wlp1s0: send auth to 70:5d:cc:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381363.3630] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381363.3630] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 kernel: [ 1020.730154] wlp1s0: authenticated
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: Trying to associate with 70:5d:cc:xx:xx:xx (SSID='pap_2g' freq=2432 MHz)
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 kernel: [ 1020.736952] wlp1s0: associate with 70:5d:cc:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381363.3776] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381363.3777] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 kernel: [ 1020.844358] wlp1s0: associate with 70:5d:cc:xx:xx:xx (try 2/3)
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 kernel: [ 1020.902594] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from 70:5d:cc:xx:xx:xx (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=1)
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: Associated with 70:5d:cc:xx:xx:xx
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully (based on lower layer success)
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 kernel: [ 1020.929119] wlp1s0: associated
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381363.5699] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4way_handshake
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381363.5699] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> 4way_handshake
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 70:5d:cc:xx:xx:xx [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 70:5d:cc:xx:xx:xx completed [id=0 id_str=]
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381363.6747] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381363.6748] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "pap_2g"
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381363.6748] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381363.6750] device (wlp1s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381363.6759] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 avahi-daemon[642]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp1s0.IPv6 with address fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx.
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 avahi-daemon[642]: New relevant interface wlp1s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jan 16 14:02:43 xxxxxx-laptop2 avahi-daemon[642]: Registering new address record for fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx on wlp1s0.*.
Jan 16 14:02:45 xxxxxx-laptop2 google-chrome.desktop[2897]: [2891:2920:0116/140245.599715:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
Jan 16 14:02:48 xxxxxx-laptop2 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 16 14:03:02 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381382.0385] audit: op="connection-update" uuid="f96ae302-8ebf-4cb3-9a37-cd88b303b9a5" name="pap_2g" args="connection.timestamp,802-11-wireless-security.auth-alg" pid=10052 uid=1000 result="success"
Jan 16 14:03:11 xxxxxx-laptop2 systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 16 14:03:26 xxxxxx-laptop2 google-chrome.desktop[2897]: [2891:2920:0116/140326.729741:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
Jan 16 14:03:28 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381408.6374] device (wlp1s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 14:03:28 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381408.6379] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan 16 14:03:28 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <warn>  [1705381408.6388] device (wlp1s0): Activation: failed for connection 'pap_2g'
Jan 16 14:03:28 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381408.6390] device (wlp1s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 14:03:28 xxxxxx-laptop2 avahi-daemon[642]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx on wlp1s0.
Jan 16 14:03:28 xxxxxx-laptop2 avahi-daemon[642]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp1s0.IPv6 with address fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx.
Jan 16 14:03:28 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381408.6954] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jan 16 14:03:28 xxxxxx-laptop2 kernel: [ 1066.061306] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from 70:5d:cc:xx:xx:xx by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jan 16 14:03:28 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=70:5d:cc:xx:xx:xx reason=3 locally_generated=1
Jan 16 14:03:28 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Jan 16 14:03:28 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381408.9247] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jan 16 14:03:28 xxxxxx-laptop2 NetworkManager[645]: <info>  [1705381408.9247] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jan 16 14:03:28 xxxxxx-laptop2 wpa_supplicant[686]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jan 16 14:03:29 xxxxxx-laptop2 google-chrome.desktop[2897]: [2891:2920:0116/140329.148590:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
```